# On the server, player movement is not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code renders the motion of the player, changing the picture. Locally it works fine on the server change picture is not visible. But if you uncomment the alert ("right1"); and alert ("right2"); will be seen as an image change. How do I make the server was also seen pictures change?

```
var timer;
function GoRight(toPosition, level, mines) {
    clearInterval(timer);

    var left = $("#man").position().left;
    var top = $("#man").position().top;

    $("#man").attr('style', 'position:absolute;display:block;left:' + left + 'px;top:' + top + 'px;')
    $("#man").attr("class", "");

    var tempi = 0;
    timer = setInterval(
        function () {
            if (left >= toPosition) {
                left = toPosition;
                $("#man").attr('style', 'position:absolute;display:block;left:' + left + 'px;top:' + top + 'px;')
                clearInterval(timer);
                $("#man").attr('src', '/content/games/kamikaze2/right0.gif');

                return;
            }
            tempi += 8;
            left += 8;
            $("#man").attr('style', 'position:absolute;display:block;left:' + left + 'px;top:' + top + 'px;')

            if (tempi % 16 == 0) {
             //  alert("right1");
                $("#man").attr('src', '/content/games/kamikaze2/right1.gif');
            }
            else {
             //   alert("right2");
                $("#man").attr('src', '/content/games/kamikaze2/right2.gif');
            }
        }, 70);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What you'll need to do is update your "gamestate" somehow to the server.

Comment: I just realized that the pictures change, but only if there is alert without pictures do not shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like a surprise, but it helped me a line after the if else

```
$("#man").attr('src');
```

but it works